# jQuery seems not work inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what I try to do is an button `onclick` event. When you click the button the other div is sliding down. When it slides down, it also add an `onclick` event to the button, when you use like `alert()` , `console.log()` inside the function it works just fine. But when I use like `$('#formHelper').html('New content');` nothing happens.

First, I made an [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69b0a344/) here.

No errors or anything, the codes looks like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="label label-primary">BOOTSTRAP</span> <b>Form-Helpers </b>
        <div class="pull-right"> 
             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="formHelper">Show</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="panel-body" id="formHelperShow">
    Some text
</div>
```

```
function myFn(  ) {
    $('#formHelper').html('New content');
    console.log( 'works?' );
};

$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(e)
{

    e.preventDefault();
    var div = '#'+$(this).attr('id');

    $(div)
    .html('Hide')
    .removeClass('btn-primary')
    .addClass('btn-danger')
    .attr('onclick', 'myFn()');

    $(div+'Show').slideDown(500);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(e)
{

    e.preventDefault();
    var div = '#'+$(this).attr('id');

    $(div)
    .html('Hide')
    .removeClass('btn-primary')
    .addClass('btn-danger')
    .attr('onclick', myFn);  // Here is the change

    $(div+'Show').slideDown(500);

});
```

**Edit**:

```
function myFn() {
    $('#formHelper').html('New content')
    .unbind('click').click(frstClck);
    $('#formHelperShow').slideUp(500);
};
var frstClck = function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();


    $(this)
        .html('Hide')
        .removeClass('btn-primary')
        .addClass('btn-danger')
        .unbind('click')
        .click(myFn);

    $("#"+this.id + 'Show').slideDown(500);

}


$('.btn').click(frstClck);
```

Comment: Not works as I wanted tho, first click it should update the button with text "Hide" as it do, next click when then it should update to the "New content". Your example runs the function directly. Maybe I'm doing this wrong